# Arrows at right angles on a tikzpicture matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

I'm trying to do something pretty simple but haven't been able to find an answer so far. I have a flow chart and I want to draw straight arrows at right angles instead of 'bent' arrows, inside of a `matrix` environment.
This is the code I have, and I just need a way to replace the bent arrows to the left with straight arrows bent at right angles like the ones on the right:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning,chains}

\begin{document}

% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{desicion} = [diamond, draw, text width=3em, text badly centered, inner sep=0pt]%, node distance=3cm]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, text width=10em, text centered, rounded corners]%, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse, minimum height=2em]

\begin{tikzpicture}[descr/.style={fill=white,inner sep=2.5pt}]
\matrix (m)[matrix of nodes, column  sep=2cm,row  sep=8mm, align=center, nodes={rectangle,draw, anchor=center} ]{
\node [block] {A. Campos [1;14]}; & \\
\node [block] {B. Bineado [1;4]}; & \\
\node [cloud] {call \texttt{analisis\_campo}}; & \\
\node [block] {C. Modelos [1;2]}; & \\
\node [block] {D. Extinción [1;31]}; &  \node [block] {E. Fracción de binarias [1;2]}; \\
\node [cloud] {call \texttt{analisis\_modelo}}; & \\
\node [cloud] {call \texttt{analisis\_final}}; & \node [desicion] {\scriptsize{Fin E}}; \\
\node [desicion] {\scriptsize{Fin D}}; & \\
\node [desicion] {\scriptsize{Fin C}}; & \\
\node [desicion] {\scriptsize{Fin B}}; & \\
\node [desicion] {\scriptsize{Fin A}}; & \\
\node [block] {Stop}; & \\
 };
\path [>=latex,->] (m-1-1) edge (m-2-1);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-2-1) edge (m-3-1);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-3-1) edge (m-4-1);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-4-1) edge (m-5-1);
\path [>=latex,->,dashed] (m-5-1) edge node[auto] {\scriptsize{MODEL}} (m-5-2);
\draw [>=latex,->] (m-5-2) |- (m-6-1);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-5-1) edge (m-6-1);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-6-1) edge (m-7-1);
\path [>=latex,->,dashed] (m-7-1) edge node[auto] {\scriptsize{MODEL}} (m-7-2);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-7-1) edge (m-8-1);
\path [>=latex,->,font=\scriptsize] (m-7-2) edge [bend right=60] node[descr] {No} (m-5-2);
\path [>=latex,->,font=\scriptsize] (m-8-1) edge [bend left=60] node[descr] {No} (m-5-1);
\path [>=latex,->,font=\scriptsize] (m-9-1) edge [bend left=60] node[descr] {No} (m-4-1);
\path [>=latex,->,font=\scriptsize] (m-10-1) edge [bend left=60] node[descr] {No} (m-2-1);
\path [>=latex,->,font=\scriptsize] (m-11-1) edge [bend left=60] node[descr] {No} (m-1-1);
\draw [>=latex,->,font=\scriptsize] (m-7-2) |- node[descr] {Sí} (m-8-1);
\path [>=latex,->,font=\scriptsize] (m-8-1) edge node[descr] {Sí} (m-9-1);
\path [>=latex,->,font=\scriptsize] (m-9-1) edge node[descr] {Sí} (m-10-1);
\path [>=latex,->,font=\scriptsize] (m-10-1) edge node[descr] {Sí} (m-11-1);
\path [>=latex,->,font=\scriptsize] (m-11-1) edge node[descr] {Sí} (m-12-1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here's what I get whit this code:

[image]

Comment: You can use a relative intermediate coordinate for that like `\path [>=latex,->,font=\scriptsize,draw] (m-8-1) -| ++(-3cm,2cm) node[descr] {No} |- (m-5-1);` for one of the lines.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Instead of using an `edge`, you can use a `to` operation (which has to be used with `\draw`, not `\path`). That will give you very fine control over how the nodes or coordinates are connected. You can define any arbitrary path using `to path=<path definition>`, in which `(\tikztostart)`, `(\tikztotarget)` and `(\tikztonodes)` will hold the start and end of the path and the nodes you define with the `to` operation. If you define a style containing `to path={(\tikztostart) -- ++(#1,0pt) \tikztonodes |- (\tikztotarget) }`, you can pass an argument to the style and the to path will then draw a horizontal line for a specified distance, place the nodes on that line, and then draw an orthogonal line to the target.

[image]

I've also changed your code to use the `\tikzset{<style name>/.style={<options>}}` syntax instead of the obsolete `\tikzstyle` command.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning,chains}

\begin{document}

% Define block styles
\tikzset{
    desicion/.style={
        diamond,
        draw,
        text width=3em,
        text badly centered,
        inner sep=0pt
    },
    block/.style={
        rectangle,
        draw,
        text width=10em,
        text centered,
        rounded corners
    },
    cloud/.style={
        draw,
        ellipse,
        minimum height=2em
    },
    descr/.style={
        fill=white,
        inner sep=2.5pt
    },
    connector/.style={
     -latex,
     font=\scriptsize
    },
    rectangle connector/.style={
        connector,
        to path={(\tikztostart) -- ++(#1,0pt) \tikztonodes |- (\tikztotarget) },
        pos=0.5
    },
    rectangle connector/.default=-2cm,
    straight connector/.style={
        connector,
        to path=--(\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m)[matrix of nodes, column  sep=2cm,row  sep=8mm, align=center, nodes={rectangle,draw, anchor=center} ]{
\node [block] {A. Campos [1;14]}; & \\
\node [block] {B. Bineado [1;4]}; & \\
\node [cloud] {call \texttt{analisis\_campo}}; & \\
\node [block] {C. Modelos [1;2]}; & \\
\node [block] {D. Extinción [1;31]}; &  \node [block] {E. Fracción de binarias [1;2]}; \\
\node [cloud] {call \texttt{analisis\_modelo}}; & \\
\node [cloud] {call \texttt{analisis\_final}}; & \node [desicion] {\scriptsize{Fin E}}; \\
\node [desicion] {\scriptsize{Fin D}}; & \\
\node [desicion] {\scriptsize{Fin C}}; & \\
\node [desicion] {\scriptsize{Fin B}}; & \\
\node [desicion] {\scriptsize{Fin A}}; & \\
\node [block] {Stop}; & \\
 };
\path [>=latex,->] (m-1-1) edge (m-2-1);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-2-1) edge (m-3-1);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-3-1) edge (m-4-1);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-4-1) edge (m-5-1);
\path [>=latex,->,dashed] (m-5-1) edge node[auto] {\scriptsize{MODEL}} (m-5-2);
\draw [>=latex,->] (m-5-2) |- (m-6-1);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-5-1) edge (m-6-1);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-6-1) edge (m-7-1);
\path [>=latex,->,dashed] (m-7-1) edge node[auto] {\scriptsize{MODEL}} (m-7-2);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-7-1) edge (m-8-1);
\draw [rectangle connector=2.5cm] (m-7-2) to node[descr] {No} (m-5-2);
\draw [rectangle connector=-3cm] (m-8-1) to  node[descr] {No} (m-5-1);
\draw [rectangle connector=-4cm,] (m-9-1) to node[descr] {No} (m-4-1);
\draw [rectangle connector=-5cm] (m-10-1) to  node[descr] {No} (m-2-1);
\draw [rectangle connector=-6cm] (m-11-1) to node[descr] {No} (m-1-1);
\draw [connector] (m-7-2) |- node[descr, pos=0.25] {Sí} (m-8-1);
\draw [straight connector] (m-8-1) to node[descr] {Sí} (m-9-1);
\draw [straight connector] (m-9-1) to node[descr] {Sí} (m-10-1);
\draw [straight connector] (m-10-1) to node [descr] {Sí} (m-11-1);
\draw [straight connector] (m-11-1) to node [descr] {Sí} (m-12-1) ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

## If you're using `tikz` v3.0

The syntax has changed a little for v3.0; the above code can be adapted to

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning,chains}

\begin{document}

% Define block styles
\tikzset{
    desicion/.style={
        diamond,
        draw,
        text width=3em,
        text badly centered,
        inner sep=0pt
    },
    block/.style={
        rectangle,
        draw,
        text width=10em,
        text centered,
        rounded corners
    },
    cloud/.style={
        draw,
        ellipse,
        minimum height=2em
    },
    descr/.style={
        fill=white,
        inner sep=2.5pt
    },
    connector/.style={
        -latex,
        font=\scriptsize
    },
    rectangle connector/.style={
        connector,
        to path={(\tikztostart) -- ++(#1,0pt) \tikztonodes |- (\tikztotarget) },
        pos=0.5
    },
    rectangle connector/.default=-2cm,
    straight connector/.style={
        connector,
        to path=--(\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (m)[matrix of nodes, column  sep=2cm,row  sep=8mm, align=center, nodes={rectangle,draw, anchor=center} ]{
        |[block]| {A. Campos [1;14]}               &                                             \\
        |[block]| {B. Bineado [1;4]}               &                                             \\
        |[cloud]| {call \texttt{analisis\_campo}}  &                                             \\
        |[block]| {C. Modelos [1;2]}               &                                             \\
        |[block]| {D. Extinción [1;31]}            & |[block]| {E. Fracción de binarias [1;2]}   \\
        |[cloud]| {call \texttt{analisis\_modelo}} &                                             \\
        |[cloud]| {call \texttt{analisis\_final}}  & |[desicion]| {\scriptsize{Fin E}}           \\
        |[desicion]| {\scriptsize{Fin D}}          &                                             \\
        |[desicion]| {\scriptsize{Fin C}}          &                                             \\
        |[desicion]| {\scriptsize{Fin B}}          &                                             \\
        |[desicion]| {\scriptsize{Fin A}}          &                                             \\
        |[block]| {Stop}                           &                                             \\
    };
    \path [>=latex,->] (m-1-1) edge (m-2-1);
    \path [>=latex,->] (m-2-1) edge (m-3-1);
    \path [>=latex,->] (m-3-1) edge (m-4-1);
    \path [>=latex,->] (m-4-1) edge (m-5-1);
    \path [>=latex,->,dashed] (m-5-1) edge node[auto] {\scriptsize{MODEL}} (m-5-2);
    \draw [>=latex,->] (m-5-2) |- (m-6-1);
    \path [>=latex,->] (m-5-1) edge (m-6-1);
    \path [>=latex,->] (m-6-1) edge (m-7-1);
    \path [>=latex,->,dashed] (m-7-1) edge node[auto] {\scriptsize{MODEL}} (m-7-2);
    \path [>=latex,->] (m-7-1) edge (m-8-1);
    \draw [rectangle connector=2.5cm] (m-7-2) to node[descr] {No} (m-5-2);
    \draw [rectangle connector=-3cm] (m-8-1) to  node[descr] {No} (m-5-1);
    \draw [rectangle connector=-4cm,] (m-9-1) to node[descr] {No} (m-4-1);
    \draw [rectangle connector=-5cm] (m-10-1) to  node[descr] {No} (m-2-1);
    \draw [rectangle connector=-6cm] (m-11-1) to node[descr] {No} (m-1-1);
    \draw [connector] (m-7-2) |- node[descr, pos=0.25] {Sí} (m-8-1);
    \draw [straight connector] (m-8-1) to node[descr] {Sí} (m-9-1);
    \draw [straight connector] (m-9-1) to node[descr] {Sí} (m-10-1);
    \draw [straight connector] (m-10-1) to node [descr] {Sí} (m-11-1);
    \draw [straight connector] (m-11-1) to node [descr] {Sí} (m-12-1) ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: O.O I can't believe how fast and unbelievable helpful your answer was @Jake. Thank you **so much**.

Comment: I had a similar problem, and I just spent an hour dissecting this post to understand what you wrote. Thanks for taking the time to explain this!

Comment: @Jake when I run this code, it doen't compile. I was wondering why?

Comment: @Harry tikz 3.0 does things differently- I have updated the answer to include a version that works with v3.0. Jake, I hope you don't mind :)

Answer (score 10):

Jake's answer is fine. I give another possiblity

```
\draw [>=latex,->,font=\scriptsize] (m-8-1) -- +(-3,0) |-  node[pos=.25,descr] {No} (m-5-1);
\draw [>=latex,->,font=\scriptsize] (m-9-1) -- +(-4,0) |-  node[pos=.25,descr] {No} (m-4-1);
\draw [>=latex,->,font=\scriptsize] (m-10-1)-- +(-5,0) |-  node[pos=.25,descr] {No} (m-2-1);
\draw [>=latex,->,font=\scriptsize] (m-11-1)-- +(-6,0) |-  node[pos=.25,descr] {No} (m-1-1);
```